# styled-components not applying style to custom functional react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

When using `styled-components` to style a custom functional react component, the styles are not being applied. Here is a [simple example](https://codepen.io/jjbskir/pen/xyKvOQ) where the styles are not being applied to the `StyledDiv`:

```
const Div = () => (<div>test</div>)
const StyledDiv = styled(Div)`
  color: red;
`;
```

What is the best way to make sure that the styles get applied correctly?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

From the [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component):

> The styled method works perfectly on all of your own or any
> third-party components as well, as long as they pass the className
> prop to their rendered sub-components, which should pass it too, and
> so on. Ultimately, the className must be passed down the line to an
> actual DOM node for the styling to take any effect.

For example, your component would become:

```
const Div = ({ className }) => (<div className={className}>test</div>)
const StyledDiv = styled(Div)`
  color: green;
`;
```

Modified example:

```js
const styled = styled.default
const Div = ({ className }) => (<div className={className}>test</div>)
const StyledDiv = styled(Div)`
  color: green;
  font-size: larger;
`;
const App = () => {
  return(<StyledDiv>Test</StyledDiv>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.app'))
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/react@16.5.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/react-dom@16.5.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/styled-components/3.4.9/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<div class="app"></div>
```

Comment: Adding my codepen here as I tried to understand the problem before finding this answer. Now it works! Thanks. https://codepen.io/shnigi/pen/qBapQYB

Comment: Please update the link to docs: https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component

Answer (score 14):

Using `styled(Component)` like that creates a class which is passed as a prop called `className` to the wrapped component.

You can then apply that to the root element:

```
const Div = ({ className }) => (
  <div className={className}>test</div>
)

const StyledDiv = styled(Div)`
  color: red;
`;
```

Answer (score 7):

In case you cannot change the original component (it's imported or generated), let's assume that component is a `<span>`, you may wrap it with e.g. a `<div>` and nest the css rules, like so:

```
const ComponentICantTouchWrapper = ({className}) => (
    <div className={className}><ComponentICantTouch /></div>
);
const StyledComponentICantTouch = styled(ComponentICantTouchWrapper)`
    > span {
        color: red;
    }
`;
```

Comment: `className` is the trick, it works for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to use styled components with material UI. The thought I had was to do this: (it worked in most cases)

```
const StyledTableRow = ({ className, children }) => (
    <TableRow className={className}>{children}</TableRow>
);
```